# Telerik, RadSplitButton ignores BackgroundImage property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I need to display a tiled image as BackgroundImage in a **RadSplitButton**, but when I set the `BackgroundImage` property it is ignored by the control

In the other hand, the `Image` property works as normally, but I need to set the `BackgroundImage` property.

Why this property is ignored by default, and how to fix it?.

Comment: In order to show the button background image you have to hide its fill. I have find only this one http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-it-possible-to-set-backgroundimage-to-togglebutton-instead-of-backcolor

Comment: @FeliceM thankyou, but doing it in that way the button looses the applied theme :(

Comment: Why instead you do not simply set the image instead of the background image?

Comment: Beacuse the Zoom, Tiled, Stretch and the other properties for a background image.

Comment: It is a fact that to see a background image you have to give some transparency to the top layer and this is why you loose the Theme. So rather sort out the image dimensions before using it as image for the control and use "Image" instead of backgroundImage. Good luck!

Comment: A normal Image property is drawn over the top-layer so why suppose a big problem for Telerik to do the same as default with a BackgroundImage?, if you notice it a default .NET framework control (eg: a Button) can manage a BackgroundImage without loosing the theme then this issue with Teleirk controls for me is a little bit strange. and I just can't reproduce the Tiled/Zoom/Stretch effect with a normal image (unknown size) but even if I could do it I won't spent a lot of time designing images for each specific case and DPI changes, that would be just absurd. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadSplitButton is in fact built of three different elements - action button, separator and arrow button. Each of these elements is built of other elements (fills, borders, etc). All controls in the suite are built with the [Telerik Presenation Framework](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/tpf-overview.html) and consist of multiple elements to allow greater flexibility. This way for example you can set different image/color for different elements - action part and the arrow part of the button.

In this case, the **BackgroundImage** is painted on the control, however, the element's fills are painted over it, hence it is not visible. Here is how to hide the fills in order to see the **BackgroundImage**:

```
radSplitButton1.DropDownButtonElement.ActionButton.ButtonFillElement.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Collapsed;
radSplitButton1.DropDownButtonElement.ArrowButton.Fill.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Collapsed;
radSplitButton1.DropDownButtonElement.ButtonSeparator.DrawBorder = false;
```

I see that you also want to see the theme. This however, would not be possible as you cannot see both the image and the fill, as if you see the fill, the image is hidden. Perhaps you can use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave event to apply different image for hover?